# How to config the behavior of 'stack new' so a certain lts can be used every time?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to setup the default lts version to 20.11, however no matter I tried all recommend method in this document https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#resolver-or-snapshot
if simply ignored my setting and use 20.13 anyway .
I tried

resolver:
url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/20/11.yaml

and

resolver: lts-20.11

none of these works.

Comment: `stack new <package-name> --resolver lts-20.11` should work if that's acceptable for you.

Comment: notice that if you installed `stack` with `ghcup` It will use the resolver based on the `ghc` version in the path. So if your `ghc` version is `9.2.5` it will default to `lts-20.11`